# Can I cast Uro, Titan of Nature's Wrath for free with Aluren if I'm casting it from my graveyard using its Escape ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Uro, Titan of Nature's Wrath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Uro%2C%20Titan%20of%20Nature%27s%20Wrath) is a 3 mana value with an Escape cost.

> Escape—{G}{G}{U}{U}, Exile five other cards from your graveyard. (You may cast this card from your graveyard for its escape cost.)

[Aluren](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aluren) allows me to cast cards with mana value 3 or less without paying their mana costs.

> Any player may cast creature spells with mana value 3 or less without paying their mana costs and as though they had flash.

Am I allowed to cast Uro, Titan of Nature's Wrath using its Escape ability and use Aluren to negate it's casting cost, requiring me to only exile 5 cards from my graveyard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Both the Escape ability on Uro and Aluren's ability are alternate costs for casting Uro. When you have multiple possible alternate costs, you can only choose 1 to apply. So if you apply the Escape cost, then you can cast it from your graveyard. If you apply the "free" cost, then you can't cast it from your graveyard.

> 118.9. Some spells have alternative costs. An alternative cost is a cost listed in a spell’s text, or applied to it from another effect, that its controller may pay rather than paying the spell’s mana cost. Alternative costs are usually phrased, “You may [action] rather than pay [this object’s] mana cost,” or “**You may cast [this object] without paying its mana cost**.” Note that some alternative costs are listed in keywords; see rule 702.
>
> > 118.9a **Only one alternative cost can be applied** to any one spell as it’s being cast. The controller of the spell announces their intentions to pay that cost as described in rule 601.2b.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the flash part tied to the alternate cost as well?

Comment: @JonTheMon No. Flash changes the timing for when you can cast a spell, but nothing in the full rules definition of it mentions costs or paying things.

Comment: Ok, I wondered if it could have been interpreted as "and if you cast it for this alternate cost, you may cast it as though it had flash".

Answer (score 6):

**No, Aluren does not allow you to cast Uro from your graveyard without spending mana.**

Escape and Aluren both create an alternative cost for casting a spell, and you can only choose to pay one alternative cost. The Escape alternative cost is attached to the permission it grants to cast the card from the graveyard, so if you use that permission you must pay the Escape cost.

Comment: Beat you by 8 seconds! If I keep doing that about 250 more times I'll reach your rep. :)